# how can I display set of sets without showing frozenset

Tags: python

I tried to create a set of set by using frozenset, but I wonder that is it possible to display

```
{{1,2}}
```

instead of

```
{frozenset({1,2})}
```

Input

```
t = [[], [1, 2], [5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
t1 = set(frozenset(i) for i in t)
print(t1)
```

Output

```
{frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 2, 5}), frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset(), frozenset({1, 2, 3, 6}), frozenset({5})}
```

Comment: you can't if you use `set` and `frozenset`, but why does this matter?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your class that is inherited from `frozenset` like:

```py
class myFrozen(frozenset):
    def __repr__(self):
        return set(self).__repr__()

    def __str__(self):
        return set(self).__str__()

t = [[], [1, 2], [5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
t1 = set(myFrozen(i) for i in t)
print(t1)
```

Output:

```py
{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, set(), {1, 2, 3, 6}, {5}}
```

Note that in this example, for `__repr__()` and `__str__()` functions, I am just using the default functions in `set` class. If you wish not showing the `set()` for empty sets, you can change the functions as you with to print. For instance:

```py
class myFrozen(frozenset):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{' + ",".join(str(x) for x in self) + '}'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

t = [[], [1, 2], [5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
t1 = set(myFrozen(i) for i in t)
print(t1)
# {{1,2}, {1,2,5}, {1,2,3,4}, {}, {1,2,3,6}, {5}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is less verbose output, I'd just use a quick list comprehension..

```py
print([set(s) for s in t])

# Output: [{1, 2}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, set(), {1, 2, 3, 6}, {5}]
```